# How to replace short words into full words from tweets using python

Tags: python, twitter, nlp, nltk, data-science

I am doing sentiment analysis on tweets. Most of the tweets contains short words  and i want to replace them as original/full word.

Suppose that tweet is:

```
I was wid Ali.
```

I want to convert:

```
wid -> with
```

Similarly

```
wud -> would
u -> you
r -> are
```

i have 6000 tweets in which there are lots of short words.
How i can replace them ? is there any library available in python for this task? or any  dictionary of shorts words available online?

i read answer of [Replace appostrophe/short words in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018030/replace-appostrophe-short-words-in-python) Question but it provides dictionary of appostrophe only.

Currently i am using NLTK but this task is not possible with NLTK.

Comment: I doubt there's a dictionary for this, as those words aren't standardized in any way.  I'd write your own dictionary if I were you.

Comment: [Mirriam Webster has a definition for wid.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wid) It is arguably a valid english word.  [The same is true of wud.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wud) If you find a way to use context to interpret when a word was typed incorrectly, particularly when the dictionary has an entry for that word, you should write a paper on it and publish it, I'm sure the NLP community would feel that that was an incredible achievement.

Comment: @JacobG. then it will take alot of time. what  smart way you suggest me for this ?

Comment: @ChootsMagoots okay above two have definition but i said there are lot of other words too .. like  U  r . i want to replace U -> you similarly       r -> are .. etc

Comment: SO is not great at design questions. You would do better thinking about what your requirements are and just writing some code. Example: assume that we don't want to check _all_ the words in a dataset, just those under a certain size. And we don't want to check them for perfect English, just "correct" some well-known customizations you store in a (Python) dictionary. If this is not good enough, then you need to take a step back and think about your design, requirements, APIs, etc. SO is not the place for that conversation.

Comment: I'm saying, it's very very difficult for a computer to tell a mistyping of a word from an actual word.  This is just noise.  I doubt you're going to get anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the following website has the necessary dictionary:
https://www.noslang.com/search
You can send request from you python code and get back the translation.

Here is the working code:

```
import requests
prefixStr = '<div class="translation-text">'
postfixStr = '</div'

slangText = 'I was wid Ali.'

r = requests.post('https://www.noslang.com/', {'action': 'translate', 'p': 
slangText, 'noswear': 'noswear', 'submit': 'Translate'})
startIndex = r.text.find(prefixStr)+len(prefixStr)
endIndex = startIndex + r.text[startIndex:].find(postfixStr)
print(r.text[startIndex:endIndex])
```

Comment: this site does not provide  API. And i am new in python .. can you help me that how i can send request from python and get back translation ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. please see the code above.

Comment: Hi Billal. Please comment on the code above. Does it work for you?