# How to expand and create common english contractions in text in pypsark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe that has text in it. There are some words like isn't, couldn't etc..which need to be expanded.

For example:

```
I'd -> I would
I'd -> I had
```

Below is the dataframe

**DataFrame**:

```
temp = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "Julia isn't awesome"),
    (1, "I wish Java-DL couldn't use case-classes"),
    (2, "Data-science wasn't my subject"),
    (3, "Machine")
], ["id", "words"])

+---+----------------------------------------+
|id |words                                   |
+---+----------------------------------------+
|0  |Julia isn't awesome                     |
|1  |I wish Java-DL couldn't use case-classes|
|2  |Data-science wasn't my subject          |
|3  |Machine                                 |
+---+----------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to search for a library in pyspark but haven't got it..How to achieve this?

**Output:**

```
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|id |words                                    |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
|0  |Julia is not awesome                     |
|1  |I wish Java-DL could not use case-classes|
|2  |Data-science was not my subject          |
|3  |Machine                                  |
+---+-----------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be a pyspark library to do this but you could use any python library. There are several solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790188/expanding-english-language-contractions-in-python). For example, if you go with the [pycontractions library](https://pypi.org/project/pycontractions/) then you could write a function and `apply()` it to the dataframe.

```py
from pycontractions import Contractions

# Load your favorite word2vec model - need to download this, available at pycontractions ink
cont = Contractions('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin')
# optional, prevents loading on first expand_texts call
cont.load_models()

def expand_contractions(text):
    out = list(cont.expand_texts([text], precise=True))
    return out[0]

temp = temp.withColumn('expanded_words', temp['words'].apply(expand_contractions))
```